# How to load locally stored page to WebView controll?

Tags: java, javafx, webview

I have WebView control in my application.

```
private WebView webview = new WebView();
```

i use it like this

```
webview.getEngine().load("http://google.com/");
```

and it works well, but how do i use it to load locally stored page.
For example:

```
webview.getEngine().load("file:myLocallyStoredPage.html");
```

Comment: have you tried `"file:///yourfile.html"`

Comment: Yes. moreover i use similar path to load images: new ImageView(new Image("file:red_arrow.png"));

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can create the a `URL` to pass to the `WebEngine` from a [`File`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/io/File.html) or [`Path`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/nio/file/Path.html)

```
File file = ...
URL url = file.toURI().toURL();
```

```
Path path = ...
URL url = path.toUri().toURL();
```

```
webview.getEngine().load(url.toExternalForm());
```